# I want to take input from multiple text inputs and send them to my database, but only the last input sends

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a mysql database/node backend, connected to an Angular frontend, that I am querying, specifically to send it the data from 3 simple text inputs in a form.

I believe my error is quite trivial for anyone with node/angular experience because I can successfully send my database input from one of the text inputs; however, when I try to detect and send data from all three inputs, it only sends the data from whichever input has its matching controller function as the last one (of the three) in my script.

Here is my html file and the script

```js
var button = document.getElementById("clickButton");

const app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.service('appService', ['$http', function($http){
 return {
  'getSuggestion' : function(suggestion,callback){
   $http.post('/getSuggestion', {
    'suggestion': suggestion
   }).success(function (response) {
    callback(response);
   })
   .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    callback({
     'error': true,
     'message': "Something went wrong."
    });
   });
  }
 }
}]);

app.controller('app', function($scope,appService) {
 //message send Function
 $scope.$watch('messageInput', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  //null check
  if (newValue !== null) {
   //wait for the button to be pressed
   button.onclick = function() {
    alert("USERNAME");
    //call server query function
    appService.getSuggestion(newValue, function (response) {
     $scope.suggestionCollection = response.rows;
    });
   };
  }
 });

 $scope.$watch('messageInput2', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  //null check
  if (newValue !== null) {
   //wait for the button to be pressed
   button.onclick = function() {
    alert("PASSWORD");
    //call server query function
    appService.getSuggestion(newValue, function (response) {
     $scope.suggestionCollection = response.rows;
    });
   };
  }
 });

 $scope.$watch('messageInput3', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  //null check
  if (newValue !== null) {
   //wait for the button to be pressed
   button.onclick = function() {
    alert("PASSWORD");
    //call server query function
    appService.getSuggestion(newValue, function (response) {
     $scope.suggestionCollection = response.rows;
    });
   };
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="app">

  <head>
    <title>Node app</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <div class="formFields">
    
      <form class="defaultForm" id="loginForm">
      
        <input class="loginField" type="text" name="username" ng-model="messageInput" placeholder="username"> <br>
        
        <input class="loginField" type="text" name="password" ng-model="messageInput2" placeholder="password"> <br>
        
        <input class="loginField" type="text" name="username" ng-model="messageInput3" placeholder="pass conf"> <br>
        
        <button id="clickButton" class="submitButton">submit</button>
        
      </form>
      
    </div>
    <!--<script src="Scripts/login.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$watch` for each input, and you have a `submit()` for each input. This is why you send only the input that changed. If you want to send them all together you should hold one `submit()`, means one `onClick()` that will check all new values are not null and send them to the server, something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('allInput', function (newValues, oldValues) {
    //null check
    if (newValues.user !== null && newValues.pass !== null && newValues.pass2 !== null) {
        //wait for the button to be pressed
        button.onclick = function() {
            alert("USERNAME");
            alert("PASSWORD");
            alert("PASSWORD CONF");
            //call server query function
            appService.getSuggestion(newValues, function (response) {
                $scope.suggestionCollection = response.rows;
            });
        };
    }
});
```

and the html:

```
      <form class="defaultForm" id="loginForm">

    <input class="loginField" type="text" name="username" ng-model="allInput.name" placeholder="username"> <br>

    <input class="loginField" type="text" name="password" ng-model="allInput.pass" placeholder="password"> <br>

    <input class="loginField" type="text" name="username" ng-model="allInput.pass2" placeholder="pass conf"> <br>

    <button id="clickButton" class="submitButton">submit</button>

  </form>
```

Of course `getSuggestion()` will change as well:

```
app.service('appService', ['$http', function($http){
return {
    'getSuggestion' : function(data,callback){
        $http.post('/getSuggestion', {
            'name': data.name,
            'pass': data.pass,
            'pass2': data.pass2
        }).success(function (response) {
            callback(response);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            callback({
                'error': true,
                'message': "Something went wrong."
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to watch for changes of values in all three input fields. If user types anything in any one of the three input fields, you want to send the values from all three input fields to your backend. And when user hits "Submit", you want to get values from all three input fields as well.

To solve this problem, you need two pieces:

1. set up a persistent click event handler on the button, as opposed to adding one only when some change happens. Note that in your code, you are updating this click handler each time one of the three input fields changes. This would cause the new input handler to overwrite the old one. That's why you only get the last touched value. I would recommend looking into the [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D) directive.
2. get inputs from all three form fields when any one of them is changed. This can be achieved through the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive. Or alternatively, you can put all three ngModels under one parent object and just `$watch()` that one parent object, as Hatzav Wolff suggests in his answer.

Here is how I would approach it:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("clickButton");

const app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.service('appService', ['$http', function($http){
return {
 'getSuggestion' : function(suggestion,callback){
  $http.post('/getSuggestion', {
   'suggestion': suggestion
  }).success(function (response) {
   callback(response);
  })
  .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
   callback({
    'error': true,
    'message': "Something went wrong."
   });
  });
 }
}
}]);

app.controller('app', function($scope,appService) {
  $scope.handleChange= function() {
    /* Do whatever you want with the input. They are all here */
    console.log($scope.messageInput + ' ' + $scope.messageInput2 + ' ' + $scope.messageInput3);
  }

  $scope.handleSubmit= function() {
    /* Do whatever you want with the input. They are all here */
    console.log($scope.messageInput + ' ' + $scope.messageInput2 + ' ' + $scope.messageInput3);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="app">

  <head>
    <title>Node app</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <div class="formFields">
    
      <form class="defaultForm" id="loginForm">
      
        <input class="loginField" type="text" name="username" ng-model="messageInput" ng-change="handleChange()" placeholder="username"> <br>
        
        <input class="loginField" type="text" name="password" ng-model="messageInput2"ng-change="handleChange()" placeholder="password"> <br>
        
        <input class="loginField" type="text" name="username" ng-model="messageInput3" ng-change="handleChange()" placeholder="pass conf"> <br>
        
        <button id="clickButton" ng-click="handleSubmit()" class="submitButton">submit</button>
        
      </form>
      
    </div>
    <!--<script src="Scripts/login.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```